# I didn't understand what is 's' refering to in s="1", "s=2" and so on in the SpreadsheetDocument in Openxml

Tags: openxml, spreadsheetml

Please tell me what is 's' referring to in SpreadsheetML

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BxAUJ.png]

Answer (score 1):

The s attribute in a c (for CELL) element gives the index of the STYLE applied to the cell.

Excel Open XML uses a lot of "shorthand" (very short element and attribute names) in order to keep file size as small as possible. Thus, things aren't terribly descriptive.

See also:

http://officeopenxml.com/SSstyles.php

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/documentformat.openxml.spreadsheet.cell%28v=office.14%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396